# Customize a single section

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

How can i customize the title of a single section that would be different from the titles of the other sections, for example, frame the section title exercises. Something like this picture :

[image]

Comment: Note: the duplicate is more recent, but is admittedly the same question and has more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to realize something like the picture at the top and to customize a single section, but I have three problems.
the first is the size of the title of the custom section is too small.
the second in the subject table the title of the custom section is cut in half.
the third all non-custom sections that follow the custom section are identical to the custom section. look at the pictures below.

```
   \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{trace}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\definecolor{sec}{RGB}{0,163,243}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% OK! %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysec[2][\DefaultOpt]{%
    \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}{}{0.5ex}%
    {\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}%
            \noindent
            \color{sec}%
            \llap{\vrule width\textwidth height2ex depth0ex\hskip0.75ex}%
            \textcolor{sec}{\unskip#1}%
            \hskip0.75ex%
            \rlap{\vrule width\textwidth height2ex depth0ex}%
    \end{minipage}}[\smallskip]%
    \def\DefaultOpt{#2}%
    \section[#1]{#2}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter{The first chapter}
\section{Normal section}
Some text
\mysec{The first \\ section}
Some text
\section{The second section}
Some text
\section{The third section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]